# How to do something when modal is shown in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm using `react.js`, `redux` and `redux-modal`. I want to execute a code when my modal is shown.

When I put my code in `componentWillMount`, It just execute at first time.

```
  componentWillMount() {
    // Just execute one time
    // Do something
  }
```

`redux-modal` uses `show` state variable to show or hide modal, therefor I used following code to handle showing event:

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    // When modal is shown
    if (!this.props.show && nextProps.show) {
       // Do something
    }
  }
```

It works well except the first time that modal is mounted.

Now I'm using `componentWillMount` and `componentWillReceiveProps` together to handle modal show event.

**Is there any better solution to handle modal show event?**

Answer (score 2):

You could simply put the code inside your render function, like this:

```
render() {
  {(this.props.show) ? <MyModalComponent/> : null}
  ... // other components to render
}
```

If you use `componentDidMount()` to fire an API call, then with the above code, your flow will be:

- first render: `this.props.show == false`
- `render()` is run, component will be rendered without modal
- `componentDidMount()` is run, which fires API call
- result of API call updates store, setting `show` to true
- store update triggers new render cycle
- next render cycle: `this.props.show == true`
- `render()` is run, component will be rendered with modal
- (`componentDidMount()` is not run, because this is the second render)

Comment: I think it is not a performant way, because I want to call an API.

Comment: If you mean performant = speed, I think both ways are equally performant. Will update answer for API call.

Comment: At first I thought you mean I should call my API in render method. Thanks, that's an option.